# C++ Memory editing- Editing assembly/writing bytes

Tags: c++, memory-management, assembly, byte

At address 10134CE0 I have

```
10134CE0 - 40 - inc eax
```

How could I change this (using C++ hopefully with `WriteProcessMemory`) to make it

```
dec eax
```

I know 40 means `inc eax` and 48 means `dec eax` but how could I change the 40 into 48?

Comment: That wouldn't tell me how to edit assembly with C++ code.

Answer (score 4):

First, if this is code and part of your program, you should make sure that the segment is writable to you. Otherwise, you cannot dynamically patch your code.

If it is, then the following will do the trick in C (C++ might benefit from using a more beautiful `static_cast<>`):

```
uint8_t *code = (uint8_t*)0x10134ce0;
*code = 0x48;
```

The first line declares a pointer and assigns it the address of your code. In the second line you then use this pointer to overwrite the original instruction.

If you are thinking about patching x86 code in general, note that simply doing this will not suffice. x86 is a packed instruction set and operations may have different lengths. In this case, overwriting one instruction with another might be hard, because the new instruction may be longer and you thereby would overwrite one or more instructions you did not mean to patch.

For such cases, you'll need to disassemble the original code and re-assemble a new instance that you use instead of your old code. For such purposes, I like using [udis86](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/) as a disassembler, and [AsmJit](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/) to create new code on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Using `WriteProcessMemory` (if appropriate):

```
uint8_t buffer;
BOOL ok

buffer = 0x48;
ok = WriteProcessMemory(<handle of the process>, 0x10134CE0, &buffer, 1, NULL);
```

But there's the question as to whether you should be writing to the memory of another process, if that's what you're doing, even if you have the permission.

Answer (score 2):

If all you're asking is "how do I write the byte 0x48 at memory location 0x10134CE0", that's:

```
*(char *)0x10134CE0 = 0x48
```

Doing the same thing in another process's memory space looks like this:

```
char val = 0x48;
BOOL success = WriteProcessMemory(target, 0x10134CE0, &val, 1, NULL);
```

Presumably you want to do more than just this, but you haven't explained what that "more" is, which is going to make it hard for anyone to answer. BjoemD made some valiant attempts at reading your mind. If he succeeded, great. If not, please tell us what else you need.