# C++ Memory Editing- Writing to current program

Tags: c++, memory, assembly

My code is-

```
BYTE newValue[] = {0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90};
*(char *)0x004C40DB = &newValue;
```

Which I am trying to make set `004C40DB` to `nop`.

In Visual C++ 2010 I get-

> ### 1>------ Build started: Project: file, Configuration: Release Win32
>
> 1>  file.cpp 1>file.cpp(138): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from
>   'BYTE (*)[4]' to 'char'
>
> 1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>
> 1>file.cpp(142): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'BYTE (*)[4]'
>   to 'char'
>
> 1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do this in the first place?? U can cause a segment exception

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Memory editing- Editing assembly/writing bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803752/c-memory-editing-editing-assembly-writing-bytes)

Comment: It looks like you didn't get your other question fully answered.  You should stick with it until you get it answered instead of creating a new question.

Comment: If I just edit the first one then would it be on the new questions page?
Also it is not a duplicate, the other one was about editing to a different application, this is about editing to the current.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use C++-style casts for your own sake.

Secondly, if you want to write a single `0x90`, why do you have an array with four of them? One is enough:

```
*reinterpret_cast<char *>(0x004C40DB) = 0x90;
```

But in all probability you need to use [`WriteProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as said in the other question, and you need to make the memory writeable first by using [`VirtualProtect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Finally, if you really need to write multiple bytes, you need to pay attention to matching data types – you cannot write a pointer-to-byte into a single byte. With `WriteProcessMemory`, you’d pass the correct size.

If you write to memory in your own process, you would use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
BYTE newValue[] = {0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90};
*(long*)0x004C40DB = *(long*)newValue;
```

If you are trying to copy four bytes then you need pointers to long not pointers to char (assuming long is four bytes).

Comment: use 'int' instead, it is 4 bytes on more systems than 'long' is.  Better yet, use std::copy