# Editing assembly bytes with C++ code

Tags: c++, assembly, memory, share, edit

I have running process (*.exe file).
At address 0x496A42 I have this asm code

```
496A42 cmp     al, 14h
```

I found it in IDA software.
How can i change this value to

```
al, 18h
```

in C++, using VirtualProtect..

I unlocked memory with VirtualProtect, but i don't know how to change this value.
Would you tell me how to edit this assembly code with C++ code?

I hope to see you answer.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean _edit_? How to overwrite that memory from c++ code?

Comment: @user0042 Yes, i need to  overwrite that memory from c++ code. I have another program, and i need to write some HOOK, to change this 1 meaning to another meaning in this program .For a example, how it was done in this topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803752/c-memory-editing-editing-assembly-writing-bytes

Comment: Why not edit the binary with a hex editor?

Comment: @iBug I need to change it automatically with code.
I'm writing some software, that allowed you to use Russian symbols in one program. And also use more symbols, than it was alloweded.\
al, 14h - means, that you can use only 20 symbols, but i want to allowed 24 symbols. it will be public software. That's why i can't use hex editor. Many people will use it.

This is will be extra plugin for another software.

Comment: @user202729 I think, this is the code of a running process. This is executable file, but when is was started - this is running process. *.exe file

Comment: Why not just modifying the executable? It should be simpler. But anyway... edit it into your question, it's not immediately clear. / I suppose you're using Windows?

Comment: / Probably you can do `WriteProcessMemory`, as explained in the linked question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11805037)

Comment: @user202729 I'm using Windows and Linux too.
I need it to add Russian symbols in NickNames to SA-MP (GTA San Andreas multiplayer) for many server's owners.
My last version of rhis plugin is here (this version alloweds to you Russian NickNames) - https://github.com/KrYpToDeN/Advanced-SA-NickName/tree/master/ASAN/Source

Now i would like to add more symbols in NickNames. I can't change hex code by hex editor, because it;s plugin for many versions of this plugin. And for future versions.

How i know, i can't use WriteProcessMemory in Linux.
Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: @user202729 I can edit asm fuction. But i can't edit one line.

Comment: And if it's your own process you could just create a pointer to the address in question: LPSTR ptr = (LPSTR)0x....; and then *ptr = n??;

Comment: `496A42` doesn't look like the right machine code for `cmp     al, 14h`.  The last byte of the instruction should be the imm8 (`14h` in this case), and normally that instruction would use the 2 byte short encoding for AL.

Comment: @PeterCordes `496A42` is the address, not the machine code.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir No, it's **different** process.

Comment: Ok, well check the instruction encoding to be sure, but probably the `14h` will be the 2nd byte of a 2-byte instruction (at that address).

Comment: @PeterCordes But... the question is how to write, not what to write.

Comment: @KrYpToDeN For Linux probably you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20819978).

Comment: VirtualProtect changes protections on pages in your own process, doesn't it?  But you say you want to modify memory in a different process, so you're not on the right track there.  IMO just modify the executable on disk instead of changing it at run-time as user202729 recommended.  You have to find the right instruction in each new version of this plugin, so writing a program to modify the executable on disk is probably just as easy as a run-time search/modify, if not easier.

Comment: @PeterCordes `VirtualProtect()` changes protections in the calling process. `VirtualProtectEx()` changes protections in another process.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir After this action my program was crashed.

Comment: @PeterCordes,
http://s015.radikal.ru/i331/1712/21/f58885943cfdt.jpg - Assembly code
http://s42.radikal.ru/i096/1712/1f/f0a182b82fcet.jpg - ASM hex code.

The special feature of rhis plugin, that it should do this hook by itself. Without user work.

Comment: Post image links on Stack Overflow's imgur, not some ad-filled site that doesn't display anything with my adblock enabled.

Comment: OP: mind you, there may be other inner-working buffers limited to original 14h size, so if you switch-off the max-length check somewhere early, you may end with code, which will accept more characters, but will start to act weird/crash in some other part, where the new chars did overwrite some other information in memory. Unless you did go through the whole inner code and you are sure it is capable to handle 18h names, I would not patch it. If it would be my game, by 99% that would break it, as I don't keep junk bytes around (1% is for junk space from padding, but I would rather adjust max).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that ASLR is not enabled, and the .exe is loaded into the default imagebase of 0x400000 and your address is inside the .exe module

The "cmp al, 14" instruction has the corresponding bytes
0x3C 0x14

0x3C would be at address 0x496A42 and the 0x14 operand would be at address 0x496A43

So you overwrite the byte at address 0x496A43 with 0x18

```
void Patch(char* dst, char* src, int size)
{
    DWORD oldprotect;
    VirtualProtect(dst, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldprotect);
    memcpy(dst, src, size);
    VirtualProtect(dst, size, oldprotect, &oldprotect);
}

Patch((char*)0x496A43, "\x18", 1);
```